# De-reference a TObject back to an Integer

Tags: delphi, jedi

I have a function from the Jedi JCL RunningProcessList that is defined as follows....

```
procedure RunningProcessesList(AList: TStrings; ABoolean: Boolean)
```

The documentation states that the function places the running binary name in the `AList.Strings[n]` index and the process id in the `AList.Objects[n]` as a pointed to an integer.

How do I de-reference this to get the actual value. In the function it is assigning the values as follows.

```
List.AddObject(FileName, Pointer(ProcEntry.th32ProcessID));
```

where `ProcEntry: TProcessEntry32;`

How do I get the PID assigned to the `Objects` field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PID is

```
PID := DWORD(List.Objects[Index]);
```

Where Index is the index of the item of interest.

Comment: For newer versions of Delphi (the ones that can do 64-bit) you should probably use NativeInt instead of DWORD.

Comment: @HEARTWARE No, a PID is always a 32 bit DWORD

Comment: @HEARTWARE Yes you can. It truncates the high dword.